# Android emulator to work with Delphi 10.4.2

Tags: android, delphi, emulation, houdini

I am looking for an android emulator (nox, BlueStacks, etc.) to work while I'm writting android apps to speed up the testing.

I found lots of tutorials showing how to connect the emulator but my problem is that none of my apps created with Delphi (even just a button and a showmessage) are able to work with this emulators (they are supposed to have libhoudini installed) the app starts and closes.

Is anyone working with an emulator and the binaries created with Delphi work? I just tried all the new emulators, and I could not download the old ones (the ones I see un the tutorials)

Any hint is appreciated

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I managed to have a decent environment with GenyMotion + libHoudini + tcpip debug.

First, install Genymotion https://www.genymotion.com/

Then, update the libhoudini at https://github.com/m9rco/Genymotion_ARM_Translation

Finally, I could do app test through tciip which was not a problem because Genymotion shows virtual device IP.

I cannot debug, but I can launch the application pretty fast and with logs I am able to debug...